# V4 Api Created Events not available in app

Tags: social-tables

Though receiving a 200 response from a post to your /4.0/events endpoint, including the parameter deleted: 0, these events are not accessible within the web app. When attempting to reach them via direct link, I'm informed that they've been deleted.

617b2de0-4e46-11e8-9032-b788a51bbe70
39e639b0-4e36-11e8-9032-b788a51bbe70

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you send me the POST payload and the endpoints you're hitting more specifically? Can you also add the link you're trying to redirect to?

Comment: Request:

{"accept-encoding"=>["gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3"], "accept"=>["*/*"], "user-agent"=>["Ruby"], "content-type"=>["application/json"], "authorization"=>["Bearer [REDACTED"], "connection"=>["close"], "host"=>["api.socialtables.com"], "content-length"=>["134"]}

Comment: Payload:
{\"name\":\"Universal Music\",\"has_time\":0,\"deleted\":false,\"start_epoch\":1527892200,\"end_epoch\":1527904800,\"venue\":\"65327\",\"type\":\"event\"}

Comment: Endpoint:
https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/events

Response:
200 OK

Comment: Response Body is too long to post the whole thing, but data is 

data\":{\"id\":\"fec069a0-4eda-11e8-ab8f-05976af04f5a\",\"name\":\"Universal Music\",\"type\":\"event\",\"description\":null,\"start_epoch\":1527892200,\"end_epoch\":1527904800,\"archived\":0,\"deleted\":0,\"status\":\"ACTIVE\",\"has_time\":0,\"timezone\":null,\"legacy_id\":null,\"created_at\":\"2018-05-03T14:05:11.000Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2018-05-03T14:05:11.000Z\",\"industry\":null}

Comment: Link I'm attempting to access is:

https://app.socialtables.com/?event=fec069a0-4eda-11e8-ab8f-05976af04f5a&user_key=[Access token]

These area also not showing in the app itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Josh -- you need to redirect them to `https://home.socialtables.com/events/{EVENT_ID}` that is returned via the post response. You're hitting the V4 API, and `app.socialtables.com` is our V2 app.